Multiplying a column with a constant after a date in Bash
My file has two columns containing the date and the precipitation in mm for every day.
2024/01/01 5
2024/01/02 0
...
2024/12/26 15
2024/12/27 0

Now I will multiply the second column of the file after a certain date with a constant.
awk '$2=$2*0.86'  <file>

will multiply all values of the second column with 0.86.
But how can I multiply only the values after a certain date with the constant?

(1) May we assume that lines in the file are sorted by date (like the example suggests)? (2) May we assume the "certain date" occurs in the file?

Yes, the lines are sorted by date, and the file containes a line for all the dates.

If the lines are sorted by date and exactly one line with the "certain date" occurs in the file, then you can use the presence of the "certain date" as a trigger that changes the factor you multiply by:
awk -v factor=1 '
{$2=$2*factor; print}
$1 == "2024/01/02" {factor=0.86}
' file


Using any awk:
$ awk '$1 > "2024/01/02" { $2 *= 0.86 } 1' file
2024/01/01 5
2024/01/02 0
...
2024/12/26 12.9
2024/12/27 0


Using mlr:
$ mlr --nidx put 'strptime($1, "%Y/%m/%d") >= strptime("2024/12/26", "%Y/%m/%d") && is_numeric($2){ $2 *= 0.86 }'file


Since that date format sorts the same chronologically and lexically, you can do simple string comparison. With perl:
perl -spe 's{^\s*(\d\d\d\d/\d\d/\d\d)\s+\K[\d.]+}{$1 ge $min ? $& * $factor : $&}e
          ' -- -factor=0.86 -min=2024/07/14 < your-file

Beware that in your:

awk '$2=$2*0.86'


You're using the result of that assignment as the condition (with the default action being {print}), so it will delete the lines for which $2 is 0 or not a number.
Also beware that once you assign something to one of the fields (here $2), the original spacing between the fields will be lost, replaced with one space character (the default value of OFS).
The perl approach above preserves the original spacing (\K Keeps what's on the left of it).
May also be worth noting that the default floating point formatting for output for awk (OFMT) is %.6g (so would turn 100000.5 to 100000 and 1000000.1 to 1e+06 for instance), while it's %.15g in perl.
